# How to select max value on second primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id | version | name
 1      1      name1 v1
 1      2      name1 v2
 1      3      name1 v3
 1      4      name1 v4
 2      1      name2 v1
 2      2      name2 v2
 2      3      name2 v3
```

I'm trying to get the max version of every id on the table with this query:

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(a.version) AS version, b.name
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT * FROM table1
) b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.version = b.version
GROUP BY a.id
```

But I get these results instead:

```
 id | version | name
 1      4      name1 v1
 2      3      name2 v1
```

When I should get this:

```
id | version | name
 1      4      name1 v4
 2      3      name2 v3
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

EDIT:

I just realized that adding max(b.name) in the select statement does the trick hehe

Anyway, thanks to @bluefeet, @user2001117, @rs. and @Bram Gerritsen. All of your queries work like a charm =)

Comment: What happens if you add b.name to the GROUP BY statement?

Comment: Also possibly try ON a.id = b.id AND MAX(a.version) = b.version. Don't know if this is legal syntax, but....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.version, a.name
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, max(version) version FROM table1
GROUP BY id
) b
USING(id, version)
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
SELECT a.id, a.version, a.name
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, max(version) version FROM table1
GROUP BY id
) b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.version = b.version
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 SELECT a.id, a.version, a.name
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, max(version) version FROM table1
    GROUP BY id
    ) b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.version = b.version
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter your query to use the aggregate in the subquery. Once you get the `max(version)` for each `id` in the subquery you will join that back to your table on both of those values and it will return the correct result:

```
select a.id,
  a.version,
  a.name
from table1 a
inner join
(
  select max(version) MaxVersion, id
  from table1 
  group by id
) b
  on a.id = b.id
  and a.version = b.maxversion
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c2a5/3)